# Is there a way to change the default generated code wrapping width in the Delphi IDE Editor?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2009

Now that I have a widescreen monitor, I can't seem to find a way to make the Delphi IDE wrap generated code at anything other than 80 chars.  I've set the "Right margin" setting in the IDE Editor options to a high value, but it doesn't appear to affect the wrapping that happens on generated events and code lines.  Does anyone know of a way to set it? Perhaps a hidden registry setting?  Alternately, are there any IDE addons that do this?  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In D2007 and up, setting Tools|Options|Editor Options|Display|Right margin to 100 causes the event generated from the Object Inspector to wrap after the 100th character...

I just tried :

```
procedure TForm7.AVeryLongMethodNameqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
```

Comment: Same in D2006. Galileo DOES have some advantages over D7 (would hate to lose refactoring and SyncEdit as well)

Comment: Thanks!  I just tested on D2009 and you are right on.  I thought I had already tested that, but I must have been looking at an event I generated with the lower setting.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Those events which are inserted using code templates can be modified by editing the template files (they are xml documents in the C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\xxxx\ObjRepos\Code_Templates\Delphi directory)

As far as I know there is no plugin or setting to change where generated code wraps outside of templates.

Comment: Thanks.  I meant code inserted by selecting VCL events or class completion, not live templates.

Comment: I covered both, I believe that the generated code from VCL events or class completion is hard coded at 80 and that there is no current setting to change this.

Answer (score 2):

For Formatter:

> Tools > Options - Formatter > Delphi > Line breaks - General > Right
>   margin

Answer (score 1):

Until the IDE offers a little more flexibility or configuration in this area, one option might be to use a code formatting tool to tidy up the code inserted by the IDE.

Delphi 2010 will come with a highly configurable code formatter "built in", but there are other alternatives available now.  One which comes with an IDE plug-in is the [JEDI Code Formatter](http://jedicodeformat.sourceforge.net/), and the information pages for that contain references to other alternatives which may be of help even if the JEDI solution itself is not.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have to take a look at those.